# How can I make an executable python script run inside the current virtual environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv

So what I'm trying to do is have an executable python script so that I can link to it on my path and run it from anywhere, but I need to run it within a virtual environment locally.

Currently I have a symbolic link in /usr/local/bin -> ~/dev/project/tools/rest_client.py

Inside the project directory the permissions are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 luke  staff  3229 Dec  3 10:21 rest_client.py
```

The rest-client file

```
#!/Users/luke/Envs/py2.7/bin/python

def main():
   #do stuff
```

I can run it from any directory like this when I run `rest-client`

I would like to be able to check this file into a git repo and share it with others, without hardcoding the virtualenv into the file, but to still be able to execute it from anywhere on my machine.

If I change the first line to

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Then it wont run in the virtual environment unless I execute it via

```
workon py2.7
python ~/dev/project/tools/rest_client.py
```

Is there a proper way to do this is UNIX without using something like an alias?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put `#!/usr/bin/env python` as your shebang line to inherit the current python environment.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but I don't think this would work.  It seems like you wouldn't want to inherit the current python environment, but rather inherit the desired environment for a specific python project.  For example, if I have a rest_client executable that depends on the `requests` python package, I would want the executable to work all the time, not just when I happen to be in a virtualenv that has `requests` installed.  The original asker specified that they want to be able to "run it from anywhere".

Comment: @ChristopherShroba you can `print(sys.version_info)` at runtime to see which python interpreter is being used. The above answer means that it would be using the default python interpreter when used without activating the env, but will use the `venv`'s version when the env is activated.